# Laravel protected API route response returns HTML instead of JSON

Tags: reactjs, laravel, jwt

I made a Laravel/React application using the token based authentication from this source: https://medium.com/@Gbxnga/token-based-authentication-with-react-and-laravel-restful-api-83f16581e85 But everytime I try to fetch data from a protected resource I get HTML as response instead of JSON.

I used their middleware for protection of my API calls. That are jwtMiddleware:

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        try {
            $user = JWTAuth::toUser($request->input('token'));
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            if ($e instanceof TokenInvalidException){
//                return $next($request);
                return response()->json(['error'=>'Token is Invalid']);
            }else if ($e instanceof TokenExpiredException){
//                return $next($request);
                return response()->json(['error'=>'Token is Expired']);
            }else{
//                return $next($request);
                return response()->json(['error'=>'Something is wrong']);
            }
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

API:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $response = $next($request);
    $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Content-Type, Content-Range, Content-Disposition, Content-Description, X-Auth-Token');
    $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    //add more headers here
    return $response;
}
```

In my API routes I have this for my protected API calls:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['jwt.auth','api-header']], function () {

    // all routes to protected resources are registered here
    Route::get('users/list', function(){
        $users = App\User::all();

        $response = ['success'=>true, 'data'=>$users];
        return response()->json($response, 201);
    });

});
```

And in this function I try to fetch the list of users like they did on the website:

```
   componentDidMount() {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('jwtToken');
        axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user/list?token=${token}`)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
                return response;
            })
            .then(json => {
                if (json.data.success) {
                    alert("Login Successful!");
                } else alert("Login Failed!");
            })
            .catch(error => {
                alert(`An Error Occured! ${error}`);
            });
    }
```

But my response gives me this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#db5945">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="bxHaQn6jmnsoAkW7OQ8OVY9pPVy9VgpPJurFyzYS">

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json" >
    <link href="/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <title>Application Name</title>

</head>
<body>
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Can anyone explain to me why I am getting my HTML page as a response instead of the JSON response I'm sending back? I checked if the JWT Auth token are the same as in the database when I log in and it's exactly the same. So it shouldn't be because of a bad token.

Comment: this is probably an error page, Have you tried accessing your API endpoint on Postman to see if its working

Comment: Didn't try that yet forgot about Postman. I'm gonna take a look @Flash

Comment: it saves you a lot of life @Baspa

Comment: In Postman I still get the same HTML @Flash

Comment: try to ```return $response;``` not the one u typed json staff

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately.. I also tried to return some different responses like data dumping the whole response but I still get the HTML as response.. @Flash

Comment: unfortunately i am not of so much help here, but i would have advised you to do your API in Dingo API then add JWT for auth. Dingo saves me a lot of hustle all the time

Comment: your route is `users/list` but in js you make call to `user/list`

Comment: and try to add header  `Accept: application/json` to your postman requests

Comment: That did the trick.. thank you very much @AndriyLozynskiy